# Composite primary key and Dynamic Data Entity Web Site

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm trying to create simple website for database using Dynamic Data Entity web site.

Generated from DB data model contains 3 fields:

ID (part of primary key)
Lang (part of primary key)
Title (nullable)

When I try to insert new row (via generated website), I can modify only ID and Title. But Lang is invisible.

So, I cannot edit "Lang" key (part of primary key).

When I set [ScaffoldColumn(true)] for this column (in designer or in partial class), I recevie error:

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Lang'

Comment: its mean that this column has some values other then null

OR

Its May u reference this column in any other table as foreign key

Comment: You should never be able to edit a primary key in any front end. If `Lang` is a text field with a meaningful value you should normalize it out in a table `Languages` (I think).